# ImportError: No module named tests_utils. When I use ./manage.py test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, importerror

When I try to run my django tests using 'manage.py test app_name' I get an error.

```
File "path/site/ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 140, in get_runner
    test_module = __import__(test_module_name, {}, {}, force_str(test_path[-1]))
ImportError: No module named tests_utils
```

Comment: And how do you run your django tests, exactly? Django is looking for a `test_utils` module to run, but cannot find it. Isn't that a clue?

Comment: First I run my virtualENV with source ./ENV/bin/activate Then I run django test with command - ./manage.py test

Comment: Can you show me your sys.path?

Comment: did you find the answer to this problem?